# How to force Canon 200D to remember the last shoot settings when I turn it off?

Tags: canon, camera-controls

I've just bought a Canon 200D and I'm facing an annoying issue where the camera doesn't remember the last drive mode and flash settings after I turn it off (in automatic mode). Is there any way to make the settings permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to make the settings permanent?

Yes. Take the camera out of Automatic Exposure and Automatic flash modes.

Your camera remembers the last used settings in **Manual**, **Av**, and **Tv** exposure modes. It remembers most of the settings in **P** exposure mode but will calculate what it judges to be the best combination of Tv and Av for each individual shot.

In the modes listed above, the camera also remembers your last used flash settings if the internal flash is enabled or an external TTL compatible flash is connected to the camera.

In the fully automatic and scene modes the camera assumes you want the camera to make all of the decisions for you.